# Getting last reboot time

Tags: c#, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying the build date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600962/displaying-the-build-date)
>   [How to know when was Windows started or shutdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407286/how-to-know-when-was-windows-started-or-shutdown)

for my purposes I am writing a C# executable that will calculate the difference in time (minutes) from the time right now and the time the server was last rebooted.

What I am currently doing now is capturing and parsing the output from cmd -> "net stats server" and creating a new `DateTime` object then comparing that with `DateTime.Now` with a `TimeSpan` object.

Is there a cleaner way to do this **without the use of 3rd party downloads**? I am scared that not all date formats from "net stats server" are in the format that I will expect.

**edit my bad, this is a duplicate, but for what it is worth my solution was using this:

```
float ticks = System.Environment.TickCount;
Console.WriteLine("Time Difference (minutes): " + ticks / 1000 / 60);
Console.WriteLine("Time Difference (hours): " + ticks / 1000 / 60 / 60);
Console.WriteLine("Time Difference (days): " + ticks / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
```

Comment: when you reboot just look at your watch

Comment: works for scheduled reboots =) but if server suddenly crashes and starts up, I need to perform actions iff this reboot was "unscheduled"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/972189/237917) should help you. If you want to know when the system was last rebooted just take the uptime value and subtract it from the current date/time

**code from linked answer**

```
public TimeSpan UpTime {
    get {
        using (var uptime = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time")) {
            uptime.NextValue();       //Call this an extra time before reading its value
            return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(uptime.NextValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with powsershell using the WMI in it

```
$wmi = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "RemoteMachineName"
$wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.LastBootUpTime)
```

Something like this...

A very useful link if you decide to go with this route and want to know more on powershell using WMI http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/powershell-wmi-methods/