# C# Windows 10 find out when system was started

Tags: c#, windows-10

Is there any way to find out when Windows 10 was started? [Advices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972105/retrieve-system-uptime-using-c-sharp)
from this page don't work properly. They return time of the last restart, and don't consider shut down events. I think it is connected with Windows 10 [fast startup function](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html). Probably someone knows how to get a right result without switching off this feature.

Comment: Have you given [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407286/how-to-know-when-was-windows-started-or-shutdown) a try?

Comment: yep, i tried some of these. The result is always the same.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this function, i'm using it:

```
DateTime start()
    { 
        DateTime d = new DateTime();
        return d.AddMilliseconds(Environment.TickCount);
    }
```