# How can i detect when windows boots up and capture it using .Net / C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, detection

Im working on trying to find a way to detect when windows boots up and i need to capture it using .net and C#. And i dont have an idea on how i should start this. Can someone suggest me on how i should do this?

Comment: What means *capture*? I understand it as if you want to run your application. If you just need the time, then see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7407286/1997232).

Comment: i need to find the the time and the number of times the system has been booted up by the user. i need to use it in a .net application

Comment: WMI + Event Log is one way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407286/how-to-know-when-was-windows-started-or-shutdown

Answer (score 0):

The simplest ways to do so, would be to either

1. Add a shortcut from your program in the Windows Startup folder ("C:\Users%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")
2. Or you could create youre program as Service and set the startup type to Automatic

Comment: Option 1 would only detect the logon of the given user, not a boot up.

Comment: i need to track the time and the number of times the user has booted up the system. i need to use it in an application