# How to get Server Configuration in C#

Tags: c#

How can i get the Server configuration like System Name, SERVER Name, CPU, Physical memory, commit memory, last boot etc.,

Thanks in advance,

Prasad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get info from remote server you can use smth like this:

```
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem";           
        ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions();
        if (machineName != "127.0.0.1") // if it is localhost an error'll occur
        {
            connection.Username = admLogon;
            connection.Password = admPassword;
        }
        connection.EnablePrivileges = true;
        connection.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

        ManagementScope managementScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + machineName + @"\root\CIMV2", connection);
        managementScope.Connect();

        ObjectQuery queryObj = new ObjectQuery(query);
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new   ManagementObjectSearcher(managementScope, queryObj);

        foreach (ManagementObject managementObj in searcher.Get())
        {
           string osName = managementObj.Properties["Caption"].Value.ToString();
           string systemName = managementObj.Properties["csname"].Value;
           string osVersion = managementObj.Properties["Version"].Value;
           string manufacturer = managementObj.Properties["Manufacturer"].Value;
           //etc
        }
```

Comment: Here what is the machinename i have to give?

Comment: @VaraPrasad.M seriously?  How can we know what machines you have in your environment?

Comment: machinename can be its ip or full name like myserver.example.com

Comment: I am using the following code to get the CPU usage

PerformanceCounter myCounter;
myCounter = new PerformanceCounter();

myCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
myCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
myCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

for(int i=0; i < 20; i++)
myCounter.NextValue();

I ran this progam i am seeing values 0 or 100%, but when i see the task
manager the CPU usage is 6 to 22 %.

Am i missing something

Comment: I hope, this article can help you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2006/06/02/618156.aspx

Comment: @thezar The current URL is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bclteam/how-to-read-performance-counters-ryan-byington

Answer (score 4):

[`System.Environment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) and `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()` offer good starting points for some of this information (although the second is more about the current process, rather than system wide).

For things like memory counts and CPU usage you will likely want to use Peformance Counters.

The topic [Using System Monitoring Components on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aaaxk5bx.aspx) offers a good intro into how to do this stuff.

For boot times you might find this other SO useful: [Get the date-time of last windows shutdown event using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631933/get-the-date-time-of-last-windows-shutdown-event-using-net)

Comment: How can we get the server last login, last shut down?

Comment: for the last shutdown - did you read the answers on the other SO I link to?  I'm not going to copy and paste everything from that question into this answer - that's not the done thing.

Comment: for the local system i am able to get the last time shut down but for the server last time shut down how can i get?

Comment: then read the registry remotely - supply a different machine name when opening the registry key.  You'll need permissions to do that.