# How to Get Last Shutdown Time using C#

Tags: c#

I have an application, that needs to get the last shutdown time. I have used EventLog class to get the shutdown time. I have separate class file that is designed to read/write event log. ReadPowerOffEvent function is intended to get the power off event.

```
public void ReadPowerOffEvent()
    {
        EventLog eventLog = new EventLog();
        eventLog.Log = logName;
        eventLog.MachineName = machineName;

        if (eventLog.Entries.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = eventLog.Entries.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                EventLogEntry currentEntry = eventLog.Entries[i];

                if (currentEntry.InstanceId == 1074 && currentEntry.Source=="USER32")
                {
                    this.timeGenerated = currentEntry.TimeGenerated;
                    this.message = currentEntry.Message;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But whenever it tries to get the event entry count, it throws an IOException saying "The Network Path Not found". I tried to resolve, but I failed. Please help me out...

Comment: You can use [this answer][1] to determine the uptime using WMI.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972105/retrieve-system-uptime-using-c-sharp

Comment: I think this old question help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631933/get-the-date-time-of-last-windows-shutdown-event-using-net

Comment: @Kane, I did this System Up time thing already in my application. My problem is to get the time when the PC was last shutdown, and to detect whether it was poweroff event or restart and calculate the Shutdown time. That's why I need to use EventViewer. anyways, thanks.

Comment: Something wrong with "machineName".  Maybe it is turned off?

Answer (score 1):

I think you sent wrong Log name, this worked for me

```
EventLog myLog = new EventLog();
myLog.Log = "System";
myLog.Source = "User32";

var lastEntry = myLog;
EventLogEntry sw;
for (var i = myLog.Entries.Count -1 ; i >=0; i--)
{
    if (lastEntry.Entries[i].InstanceId == 1074)
        sw = lastEntry.Entries[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the "Remote Registry" service running on your machine (or the machine you want to run this app on). I suspect that this service in set to manual start on your machine. You may have to change the setting on this service to automatic.

If this app is going to be running on other machines, you may want to put some logic into your app to check  to make sure this service is running first. If it isn't then you will need to start it up through your app.

Note:

> The "Remote Registry" service enables remote users to modify registry setting on your computer. By default, the "Startup type" setting for the "Remote Registry" service may be set to "Automatic" or "Manual" which is a security risk for a single user (or) notebook PC user.
>   So, to make sure that only users on your computer can modify the system registry disable this "Remote Registry" service.