# Get the date-time of last windows10 shutdown event

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-10, shutdown

I have a small program, which detects last shutdown event of the OS.
I used the code from aplyied answer from here:

[Get the date-time of last windows shutdown event using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631933/get-the-date-time-of-last-windows-shutdown-event-using-net)

Works fine, but in windows 7.
Now I migrated to windows 10, and here DateTime of Shutdown event is saved not properly.
Instead of today, I got date for 1 month and 4 days earlier.
Why so? Why this DateTime in Registry Editor is stored wrong? What is the difference here between Windows 7 and 10?

UPD:
Strange thing found in Event Viewer, there are stored wrong events of system shutdown:
[image]

Comment: maybe you can find some information from windows event logs?

Comment: @Lei Yang actually that is possible, but than I need to filter it and find last date and time. But I would like to know the reason why this is so big difference in windows 10. That's all.

Comment: then did you ever check the registry in win10?

Comment: @Lei Yang sure I did.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zf3KlqY5hc may help

Comment: I just test on both win8.1 and win10, both worked fine.