# How to get last system shutdown\boot time (Win10)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-core, performancecounter

I try to get last system shutdown and\or reboot.
But it not works for me.

I make reboot my machine yeasterday and make shutdown-power on 10 minutes ago.
But code says me about last shutdown - it is yeasterday.

I read this questions:

[Get the date-time of last windows shutdown event using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631933/get-the-date-time-of-last-windows-shutdown-event-using-net)

[How to know when was Windows started or shutdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407286/how-to-know-when-was-windows-started-or-shutdown)

But it is not work for my machine.

I try this code:

```
  var _rebootPerformanceCounter = new global::System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time");
   _rebootPerformanceCounter.NextValue(); 
        var uptimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_rebootPerformanceCounter.NextValue());
        var uptime = uptimeSpan.ToString();
```

And this:

```
  string sKey = @"System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows";
        using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(sKey))
        {
            string sValueName = "ShutdownTime";
            byte[] val = (byte[]) key.GetValue(sValueName);
            long valueAsLong = BitConverter.ToInt64(val, 0);
            var shutdownTime= DateTime.FromFileTime(valueAsLong);


            Console.WriteLine(shutdownTime); //THIS             
        }
```

And this:

```
   if (EventLog.Exists("System"))
        {
            var log = new EventLog("System", Environment.MachineName, "EventLog");

            var entries = new EventLogEntry[log.Entries.Count];
            log.Entries.CopyTo(entries, 0);

            var startupTimes = entries.Where(x => x.InstanceId == 2147489653).Select(x => x.TimeGenerated);
            var shutdownTimes = entries.Where(x => x.InstanceId == 2147489654).Select(x => x.TimeGenerated);
            var shutdownEvents = entries.Where(x => x.InstanceId == 2147484722);
        }
```

So, the values are same: it says that i reboot my machine last evening and do not show last power off time.
I try this code on PC and notebook with same results.
At my PC i have uninterrupted power supply unit and i turned it off.

So I'm confused. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think Windows cant separate a reboot from a restart, thats why you got the same results

Comment: but windows can - it show me only last reboot, but not shutdown-upstart time

Comment: Shutdown time doesn't always even exist. Imagine a sudden power loss, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is very simple: i should off "clever power management" with -

```
 powercfg -h off
```

And code works!