# Obtaining the logout time of the same PC as the event viewer

Tags: c#

I am creating a program that automatically registers work start/end times in my company's attendance management system.
The company's attendance management system manages login/logout times, and I would like to obtain information that matches those times.

I was able to get the login time.
I want to get the time the PC was last logged out.
I got the shutdown time using the method below.
[Get the date-time of last windows shutdown event using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631933/get-the-date-time-of-last-windows-shutdown-event-using-net)

However, the shutdown time that can be obtained using this method is the same time as the event ID "6006" in the event viewer.
I want to obtain the logout time that can be obtained using event viewer "7002".
On my PC, the shutdown time is more than 20 seconds later than the logout time.

How can I get the logout time of my PC?

---

My problem was solved as below.

```
public DateTime GetLogoutTime()
{
    string userSid = null;
    string logUserSid = null;
    List<DateTime> logoutTimeList = new List<DateTime>();

    string username = Environment.UserName;
    NTAccount nTAccount = new NTAccount(username);
    SecurityIdentifier s = (SecurityIdentifier)nTAccount.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)); 
    userSid = s.ToString();

    EventLogQuery eventLogQuery = new EventLogQuery("System", PathType.LogName);
    EventLogReader eventLogReader = new EventLogReader(eventLogQuery);

        for (EventRecord eventRecord = eventLogReader.ReadEvent(); eventRecord != null; eventRecord = eventLogReader.ReadEvent())
        {
                if (eventRecord.Id == 7002 && eventRecord.UserId != null && eventRecord.Properties.Count >= 2)
                {
                                logUserSid = eventRecord.Properties[1].Value.ToString();
                        if (userSid.Equals(logUserSid))
                        {
                                logoutTimeList.Add((DateTime)eventRecord.TimeCreated);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                continue;
                        }
                }
        }
        return logoutTimeList.Last();
}
```

Comment: If you can find the event in the event log, you could just [query the log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2464118) with your event ID.